# Pasar valor de mysql a input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola buenas tarde necesito Pasar valor de mysql a input (caja de texto),lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($nombre_host,$nombre_usuario,$contrasena_usuario,$nombre_bd);

$consulta="SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE cedula='08522002'";
$resultados=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
$fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resultados);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('nombre_cliente').value =" . $fila[1] .  "</script>";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y no sería mas simple hacerlo de este modo while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($fila)){
 $name = $row[0];
 echo "<div id='nombre_cliente'>".$name."</div>";
} finalmente con el echo puedes crear un elemento del DOM y añadirle de manera dinámica el id que deseas obtener, pues personalmente no me parece correcto la mezcla de distintos lenguajes como en este caso JS y PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al margen que el código parece estar bastante mal organizado jaja, el error que esta tirando es porque al interpretarse queda de la siguiente manera:

```
document.getElementById('nombre_cliente').value = Brayan</script>";
```

Donde Javascript esta esperando que Brayan sea el nombre de una variable y no un string.

Intenta realizar lo siguiente:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo 'document.getElementById("nombre_cliente").value ='.'"'.$fila[1].'"'.'</script>';
```

Debería funcionar de esa manera.
Saludos.

Comment: Exacto, bien visto!

Answer (score 0):

Es porque al poner $fila[1] no la estas poniendo entre comillas y eso hace que javascript la interprete como una variable. Y como esa bariable Brayan no está definida pues lanza el error.

Tendrias que cambiar esto:

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('nombre_cliente').value =" . $fila[1] .  "</script>";
```

por algo así como:

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('nombre_cliente').value ='" . $fila[1] .  "'</script>";
```

o

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('nombre_cliente').value ="."'" . $fila[1] ."'".  "</script>";
```

No he probado el código así que puede que haya errores, pero el error es ese.

Comment: La última me parece demasiado liosa. Puesto a dar opciones un par más serían estas: `...ById('nombre_cliente').value=\"{$fila[1]}\"</script>";` o esta otra `...ById('nombre_cliente').value='{$fila[1]}'</script>";`. Puedes añadirlas si quieres a la respuesta por si lo necesitan otros usuarios.

Comment: Hay muchas opciones parra hacer que funcione @OscarR, unas más bonitas que otras, lo importante es que a la persona que pregunta le quede claro  que es lo que está haciendo mal.  En este caso esta confundiendo variables con valores  y por eso no pone las comillas. Gracias por tus dos opciones adicionales.